# Python BeautifulSoup4 not nesting/iterating

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to scrape product data of off adidas and nike and am successful in getting the first product's details, but can't get it to iterate through to any additional products. It looks like this is because bs4 is not nesting items inside the  I'm pointing to into a list and therefore not allowing me to iterate. I've tried searching around for solutions, but most things I read just point to changing the parser to lxml or html5. I don't think its an issue with the site's html since I'm getting the same issue for both nike and adidas. Both chunks of code are:

Nike

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import pandas as pd

headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:61.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/61.0'}
url = 'https://www.nike.com/w/mens-shoes-nik1zy7ok'

page = requests.get(url, headers=headers)

if page.status_code == 200:
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')
    product_grid = soup.findAll('div', attrs={'class': 'product-grid__items'})

    #print(product_grid)

    products = []

    for card in product_grid:
        name = card.find('a', attrs={'class': 'product-card__link-overlay'})

        products.append(name.text)

    print(products)
```

**Reutrns**

```
['Nike Air VaporMax Flyknit 3']
```

Adidas

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import pandas as pd

headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:61.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/61.0'}
url = 'https://www.adidas.com/us/men-shoes'

page = requests.get(url, headers=headers)

if page.status_code == 200:
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html5lib')
    product_grid = soup.findAll('div', attrs={'class': 'product-container___3GvlZ'})

    #print(product_grid)

    products = []

    for card in product_grid:
        name = card.find('div', attrs={'class': 'gl-product-card__name'})

        products.append(name.text)

    print(products)
```

**Returns**

```
['NMD_R1 Shoes']
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can check the following code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import pandas as pd

headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:61.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/61.0'}
url = 'https://www.nike.com/w/mens-shoes-nik1zy7ok'

page = requests.get(url, headers=headers)

if page.status_code == 200:
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')
    product_grid = soup.findAll('div', attrs={'class': 'product-grid__items'})


    products = []

    for card in product_grid:
        names = card.findAll('a', attrs={'class': 'product-card__link-overlay'})
        for element in names:
            products.append(element.text)

    print(products)
```

The issue was in: `name = card.find('a', attrs={'class': 'product-card__link-overlay'})`.

If you print it out, you get a single name because you are doing `.find` not `.findAll`

Comment: If I findAll in instead of find it returns the error:
...
    products.append(name.text)
  File "C:\Users\Steven\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\bs4\element.py", line 1602, in __getattr__
    "ResultSet object has no attribute '%s'. You're probably treating a list of items like a single item. Did you call find_all() when you meant to call find()?" % key
AttributeError: ResultSet object has no attribute 'text'. You're probably treating a list of items like a single item. Did you call find_all() when you meant to call find()?

Comment: Check my code. I added an additional `for loop` after `card.findAll`

Comment: Sorry, totally glossed over that. You are right. Thanks for the help.